# Am I using wrong data type here?

Tags: c++builder

```
void __fastcall TForm3::Checkforupdates2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/update.html.txt";
String source = Update_Check->Get(url); // Update_Check is a TIdHTTP Object
String version = "2.2.3";

if (version == source){
      ShowMessage("Application is up to date");
    }
else{
    const wchar_t * pathw = L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AppName\\";
    const wchar_t * operationw = L"open";
    const wchar_t * filew = L"AppName Updater.exe";
    ShellExecute(NULL,operationw,filew,NULL,pathw, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }
}
```

The page I get the source from is just a text file with `2.2.3` in it. So if I'm not mistaken, `String source` should be `2.2.3` as well. But no matter what the `else{}` part is running. I also tried `ShowMessage(source)` and it gave `2.2.3`.Feel free to smite me, but I cannot see any mistake here.

Comment: Did you try looking at the contents of `source` and `version` with the debugger so you can spot any differences? If you are always going to the `else` block, then clearly there is *some* difference between `source` and `version`.  Are you sure that `source` doesn't have any hidden/nonprintable characters, whitespace, line breaks, etc in it?

Comment: make sure `.` has the same code as you are using most likely unicode there are quite a few of `.` looking codes which are visually the same but not for string comparison ... also check if there are not some hidden codes in the string it happens time to time ...

Comment: I debugged seperately and their contents were different. ‘source’ had a \n at the end and that was the reason. Thank you both for your replies @RemyLebeau and Spektre

Comment: @Peytuk: In that case, you can simply `Trim()` the `String` that `Get()` returns.  Or, use a comparison method that is not dependent on whitespace. I would parse the `source` string to extract the actual integers, such as with `swscanf()`, and then compare them instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Parsing them sounds healthier than my method (just added a \n at the end of `version` :P lazy me)

Comment: @Peytuk: an alternative solution would be to have the app retrieve its own version number from its version resource (see `GetFileVersionInfo()` and `VerQueryValue()`) and submit that to the server and let the server reply with whether or not the version is up-to-date (which would require you to write a server-side script to process the request). Even if you don't go this route, it is still a good idea to query the version resource, because it provides the `major.minor.build.release` numbers as individual integers, which you can then compare to integers you parse from the `source` string.